# Implement generic vertex and edge classes

Tags: java, generics

I would like to implement generic graph classes. These are what I came up with:

```
public abstract class VertexBase<V extends VertexBase<V, E>, E extends EdgeBase<V, E>> {
    public final HashMap<V, E> inEdges = new HashMap<>();
    public final HashMap<V, E> outEdges = new HashMap<>();
}

public abstract class EdgeBase<V extends VertexBase<V, E>, E extends EdgeBase<V, E>> {
    public final V fromVertex;
    public final V toVertex;

    public EdgeBase(V from, V to) {
        fromVertex = from;
        toVertex = to;
        from.outEdges.put(to, get());
        to.inEdges.put(from, get());
    }

    protected abstract E get();
}
```

Now the problem is that I have to implement Edge::get everywhere:

```
@Override
protected Edge get() {
    return this;
}
```

And the compiler complains that I am calling overridable method in the constructor.

Is there a way to better implement these?

Answer (score 0):

When you implement new class that extends EdgeBase, you need to replace all E type to Edge and Edge must be extends EdgeBase < V, Edge >, for example:

```
public class EdgeBaseImpl<V extends VertexBase<V, Edge>> extends EdgeBase<V, Edge> {
  ...
  @Override
  protected Edge get() {
     return this;
  }
}
```